# VB.Net ArrayList

Tags: arrays, vb.net, arraylist

I'm trying to wrap my head around array lists in vb.net. I am self teaching via the internet but can't seem to figure it all out. Some points i'm having trouble connecting the dots to:

1. How do i make the array list universal so it's not stuck in a subroutine and I can allow any sub to access the list.
2. Allowing the list to be added to or removed from from another control on the form.
3. Saving this array list so the program will populate the list box with it on startup.
4. Here is an image of the basic concept for the visual:

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5XFt.jpg

Comment: You should use `List(Of T)`.

Comment: The `ArrayList` class exists to provide dynamic array functionality. It acts much like an array but, instead of being a fixed-size, it can grow and shrink dynamically. The problem with it is that each item is an `Object` reference, meaning that any object can be added as an item and you have to cast each item as its actual type when you get it back. The `ArrayList` has been basically obsolete since .NET 2.0 and VB 2005, with the advent of generics and the `List(Of T)`. It works like an `ArrayList` except it provides type-safety so you can't add objects of the wrong type and no casting required

Comment: Question 1 is a simple matter of scope. Do some reading on variable scope.  Question 2 is meaningless because all the code in the form is part of the form.  You're not putting any code in any of the controls so nothing will be added to any list from any control.  As an example, if you handle the `Click` event of a `Button`, that event handler is part of your form, not part of the `Button`.

Answer (score 0):

Up to question 3, using a `List(Of T)` was the way to go.  It may still be but certainly not completely and maybe not at all.  Before the advent of the `List(Of T)`, Microsoft recognised that storing `Strings` in a collection was the most common requirement so, to provide type-safety in that case, they provided the `StringCollection` class.  You say that you want to persist your list of values between sessions so that probably means using `My.Settings` and it is actually possible to create a setting of type `StringCollection`.

I would suggest that you open the Settings page of the project properties and add a setting of type `StringCollection`.  Once added, that list will be automatically loaded at startup and saved at shutdown, with no code required from you.  You can access it anywhere in the app via `My.Settings` and you can call `Add` and `Remove` or index it or loop over it in exactly the same way as you would an `ArrayList` or `List(Of String)`.

There is one small gotcha with a `StringCollection` in settings though.  It will actually be `Nothing` by default.  The trick to avoiding that is to edit its `Value` on the Settings page to add an item, commit that, then edit it again to remove the item.  You'll see that, instead of the `Value` field being empty, it will then contain a snippet of XML.  It's that that creates the `StringCollection` object in the settings file.

As I said, if you want to persist this list between sessions then I strongly recommend using settings this way.  Just note that, in order to edit settings, they have to be User-scoped rather than Application-scoped.  What that means is that each separate Windows user will have their own copy of the setting and thus their own value.  If you only log into Windows with one account then it's of no consequence.  If multiple Windows users use the app then it may be considered beneficial in most cases but may be a problem if you want universal settings that can be edited. If it's a problem, you will need to handle persistence yourself but be aware that a standard Windows user (as opposed to an admin) won't have access to write data everywhere, which is exactly why User-scoped settings work the way they do.

Also, while you must use a `StringCollection` for persistence in settings, you may or may not want to use the same collection in the rest of your code.  You might access the collection directly all the time or you may choose to copy the collection to a `List(Of String)` at startup and then copy the data back at shutdown.  Unless you want to avoid committing items until shutdown, I wouldn't bother with the extra collection.

Answer (score 0):

So an important thing to know is that you can directly populate and edit the listbox without having an additional ArrayList. You would use the example code below as follows:

```
   'addTb is the text box you had in the image; this will run on button press event

    ListBox1.Items.Add(addTB.Text)
```

If you are looking to dump ArrayList data into the list box use something like this:

```
   'creates new arraylist and adds items to it
    Dim listStuff As ArrayList = New ArrayList
    listStuff.Add("Hi")
    listStuff.Add(2)

    'makes listStuff the datasource for your list box
    ListBox1.DataSource = listStuff
```

Finally, if you are wanting to loop through ArrayList items use something like this:

```
   'remember to do count - 1 or you will receive error since index will be out of range
    For i = 0 To listStuff.Count - 1
        If listStuff.Item(i) = "" Then
            'do stuff here
        End If
    Next
```

Hopefully that helps. Let me know if I need to be more clear since this is my first stack overflow answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a ListBox control to visualize a collection of presumably String values from a TextBox control. The ListBox exposes the visualized collection via the [Items](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.items(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

> How do i make the array list universal so it's not stuck in a subroutine and I can allow any sub to access the list.

Because the ListBox control resides on the Form, you can access the Items property through any access level in your Form's code.

> Allowing the list to be added to or removed from from another control on the form.

From the Items property, you can use the [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add a single value, the [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z018s5az(v=vs.110).aspx) method to add multiple values via an array or another ListBox collection, the [Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert(v=vs.110).aspx) method to insert a value at a given index, the [Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method a specific item, and the [RemoveAt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.removeat(v=vs.110).aspx) method to remove an item at a given index.

So in your case, since you're presumably adding the value from the Text property of the TextBox to the ListBox, it is as simple as:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)
```

> Saving this array list so the program will populate the list box with
>   it on startup.

You have a few options, but generally the idea is to is write each value in the Items property to its respective line at a given file when the application closes and then load each value back by reading each line from the same file. Another option is to use My.Settings, though I think with your level of expertise, it would probably be better to stick with the read/write to a file option so you don't have to worry about some pitfalls associated with this option. Here would be a quick example of reading/writing the items to a file:

```
'Write the items to the file
Dim items(ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) As String
ListBox1.Items.CopyTo(items, 0)
IO.File.WriteAllLines("file.txt", items)

'Read the items to the file
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines("file.txt"))
```

Comment: This is great information! Somehow I missed the first part you mention about adding directly to the listbox. How would one go about adding to the listbox from a secondary form. As in, you hit a button to open form2 and put your text in there. Once you hit a button, it adds it into the control (This example being the listbox). That is why I asked about making it accessible universally. If that makes sense.

Comment: You would need to qualify the control first, this simply means that you need to specify where the control resides. So for example if your ListBox is on a Form named Form1 and then you open Form2 to input your text, in your Button's click event on Form2 you would call: `Form1.ListBox1.Items.Add(TextBox1.Text)` assuming that TextBox1 is on Form2.